# HTML table as data source for highstock charts using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to make the HTML table as data source for highstock chart type of highchart lib ?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

Comment: I wanted the data table structure for highstock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define dates instead of categories.

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/ysxo739h/

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Jane</th>
        <th>John</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>2006-01-01</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2006-01-02</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```